# Привязать обработчик к ListViewItem

Tags: c#, uwp

Динамически заполняю ListView. И после этого хочу привязать к элементам списка обработчик. При попытке привязки получаю исключение:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

```
private void FillListView()
{
    listView.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var item in myClicheFinder.MyCliches)
    {
        listView.Items.Add(item.Str);
    }

    foreach (var item in listView.Items)
    {
        (item as ListViewItem).RightTapped += new RightTappedEventHandler(listView_RightTapped); //здесь исключение
    }
}

private void listView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lVcontextMenu.ShowAt((ListViewItem)sender);
}
```

Comment: А какого типа у вас свойство `Str`?

Comment: @andreycha, строкового

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что потом обращаетесь к этим строкам и приводите их к `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике, какой тип у `item` во втором цикле.

Comment: @andreycha listView.Items = {Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemCollection}
item = {System.String}

Но все равно непонятно как тогда к элементам ListView прикрутить обработчик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в `ListView.Items` добавляются строки, а затем вы преобразуете их к `ListViewItem` и пытаетесь подписаться. Преобразование выдает null, и вместо нормального NRE почему-то вываливается исключение о делегате.

Чтобы обрабатывать нажатия на конкретные элементы `ListView`, подпишитесь на событие `RightTapped` самого `ListView`:

```
private void FillListView()
{
    listView.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var item in myClicheFinder.MyCliches)
    {
        listView.Items.Add(item.Str);
    }

    listView.RightTapped += new RightTappedEventHandler(listView_RightTapped);
}
```

Затем показывайте меню следующим образом:

```
private void listView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lVcontextMenu.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
}
```

Затем когда в конкретной команде меню вам нужно будет получить строку, делайте так:

```
private void menuCommand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{                        
    // значение находится в ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext
}
```

Все это будет работать, если `lVcontextMenu` -- это [приаттаченный `MenuFlyout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103117/1985167). Именно он является заменой контекстного меню в таких случаях.

Comment: Я так и делал, только у меня нельзя задать вторым аргументом позицию. (CS1501 No overload for method 'ShowAt' takes 2 arguments).
Поэтому контекстное меню вылетает не на нажимаемом элементе, а рядом со всем ListView. Не очень эстетично.

Comment: @skaborik а какого типа у вас `lVcontextMenu`?

Comment: lVcontextMenu = {Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout}

Comment: @skaborik попробуйте использовать приаттаченный `MenuFlyout`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33103117/1985167 -- именно он является заменой контекстного меню в таких случаях. Обычный же `Flyout` немного для другого предназначен.